# PHP How to connect mysql through one php file

Tags: php, mysql, connection

I'm currently working on a university project and I'm new at php. I'm looking for a solution for my problem.

My problem is, I have 10 php files related to mysql database. Everytime I want to create a php file, I have to write mysql connection codes over and over again.

Today I changed my server and now I have to change all mysql connection codes in every php file. Is there a way to connect mysql in one php file and call that page in other php files?

For example I want to parse a table from a database but I just wanna get mysql connection codes from a specific page. Is there a such solution?

Comment: Look into [`require` / `include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: @iainn - Since you included links, you won ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write database connection in another file and include this file to files with php

```
require('databaseConnection.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a separate file and use includes. Check this website: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: thank you so much. It's the exact same thing with what I was looking for ^^